# Agrupar por semana - dia que empieza la semana

Tags: sql, postgresql

El escenario es que tengo unos eventos al dia, y tengo que agruparlos por semana, de tal manera que se pueden agurpar tal que:

```
SELECT array_agg(a_day) as data,  week
FROM (
       SELECT day::date as a_day, date_trunc('week', day) :: date as week
       from generate_series(now(), (now() - interval '168 days') ::timestamp,
                            '- 1 day') as day
  ) as p
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY  week DESC
```

Y esto da tiene una salida de:

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      2018-11-29,
      2018-11-28,
      2018-11-27,
      2018-11-26
    ],
    "week": "2018-11-26"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      2018-11-25,
      2018-11-24,
      2018-11-23,
      2018-11-22,
      2018-11-21,
      2018-11-20,
      2018-11-19
    ],
    "week": "2018-11-19"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      2018-11-18,
      2018-11-17,
      2018-11-16,
      2018-11-15,
      2018-11-14,
      2018-11-13,
      2018-11-12
    ],
    "week": "2018-11-12"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      2018-11-11,
      2018-11-10,
      2018-11-09,
      2018-11-08,
      2018-11-07,
      2018-11-06,
      2018-11-05
    ],
    "week": "2018-11-05"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      2018-11-04,
      2018-11-03,
      2018-11-02,
      2018-11-01,
      2018-10-31,
      2018-10-30,
      2018-10-29
    ],
    "week": "2018-10-29"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      2018-10-28,
      2018-10-27,
      2018-10-26,
      2018-10-25,
      2018-10-24,
      2018-10-23,
      2018-10-22
    ],
    "week": "2018-10-22"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      2018-10-21,
      2018-10-20,
      2018-10-19,
      2018-10-18,
      2018-10-17,
      2018-10-16,
      2018-10-15
    ],
    "week": "2018-10-15"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      2018-10-14,
      2018-10-13,
      2018-10-12,
      2018-10-11,
      2018-10-10,
      2018-10-09,
      2018-10-08
    ],
    "week": "2018-10-08"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      2018-10-07,
      2018-10-06,
      2018-10-05,
      2018-10-04,
      2018-10-03,
      2018-10-02,
      2018-10-01
    ],
    "week": "2018-10-01"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      2018-09-30
    ],
    "week": "2018-09-24"
  }
]
```

Hasta aqui bien. 
El problema viene de que el usuario puede elegir el comienzo de semana, Siendo la establecida por `Postgres` los lunes, y por la mayoría de usuarios el domingo (pero esto implica que pueda ser un jueves o un miercoles).

Tengo los valores:

```
+-----------+-------+
|    Dia    | Valor |
+-----------+-------+
| Domingo   |     1 |
| Lunes     |     2 |
| Martes    |     3 |
| Miercoles |     4 |
| Jueves    |     5 |
| Viernes   |     6 |
| Sabado    |     7 |
+-----------+-------+
```

donde :company_date_start seria uno de estos valores

```
select array_agg(a_day) as data, week
FROM (
       select day::date as a_day, (date_trunc('week', day) - (:company_date_start || ' days')::interval) :: date as week
       from generate_series(now(), (now() - interval '60 days') ::timestamp,
                            '- 1 day') as day
     ) as p
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week DESC
```

Si es domingo el comienzo de semana, queda mas o menos bien, pero los domingos quedan atrás. Y si por ejemplo es un martes, aparecería como semana el viernes y de agrupar ni hablar.

Realmente es solo agrupar por semanas dando el que dia de la semana comienza. por lo que seria agrupar en intervalos de 7 días.

Estoy Utilizando `Postgres 11` y aquí tenéis un [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/56f78/517)

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de unos cuantos días de dolor de cabeza, lo he sacado:

```
SELECT array_agg(a_day) as data, week
FROM (
       SELECT day_g::date as a_day,

              CASE
                WHEN day_g - ((EXTRACT(DOW FROM day_g) + 1) - (first_day_week) || ' DAYS')::interval > day_g
                  THEN
                    day_g - ((EXTRACT(DOW FROM day_g) + 1) - (first_day_week) + 7 || ' DAYS')::interval
                ELSE
                    day_g - ((EXTRACT(DOW FROM day_g) + 1) - (first_day_week) || ' DAYS')::interval
                END       as week
       from generate_series(now(), (now() - interval '168 days') ::timestamp,
                            '- 1 day') as day_g
              INNER JOIN user c ON c.id = 1
     ) as p
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week DESC;
```

Es un tanto complejo de explicar. pero lo voy a intentar. Sabiendo que el `EXTRACT(DOW FROM day_g)` te va a dar el numero de la semana con estos valores:

```
+-----------+-------+
|    DOW    |  Dia  | 
+-----------+-------+
| Domingo   |     0 |
| Lunes     |     1 |
| Martes    |     2 |
| Miércoles |     3 |
| Jueves    |     4 |
| Viernes   |     5 |
| Sábado    |     6 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Entonces, puedes cuadrarlo con la tabla añadiendo +1 (en mi caso, si tu tienes otros valores puedes añadir o restar lo conveniente). Por lo que ahora el  DOW que te da, sera igual que tus valores por semana.

Luego, si al día generado le restas la diferencia entre el primer día de la semana escogida por el usuario (`first_day_week`) y  su valor en DOW, te sale el `first_day_week`  mas próximo.

Si por ejemplo tu usuario dice que son los miércoles su inicio de la semana, `first_day_week = 5`.

```
monday   2018-12-03 - ((1+ 1)- 5) = 2018-12-06
sunday   2018-12-02 - ((0+ 1)- 5) = 2018-12-06
saturday 2018-12-01 - ((6+ 1)- 5) = 2018-11-29
friday   2018-11-30 - ((5+ 1)- 5) = 2018-11-29
thursday 2018-11-29 - ((4+ 1)- 5) = 2018-11-29
wednesday2018-11-28 - ((3+ 1)- 5) = 2018-11-29
tuesday  2018-11-27 - ((2+ 1)- 5) = 2018-11-29
monday   2018-11-26 - ((1+ 1)- 5) = 2018-11-29
sunday   2018-11-25 - ((0+ 1)- 5) = 2018-11-29
saturday 2018-11-24 - ((6+ 1)- 5) = 2018-11-22
friday   2018-11-23 - ((5+ 1)- 5) = 2018-11-22
thursday 2018-11-22 - ((4+ 1)- 5) = 2018-11-22
wednesday2018-11-21 - ((3+ 1)- 5) = 2018-11-22
tuesday  2018-11-20 - ((2+ 1)- 5) = 2018-11-22
```

Aquí hay un problema por que:

```
monday   2018-12-03 - ((1+ 1)- 5) = 2018-12-06
sunday   2018-12-02 - ((0+ 1)- 5) = 2018-12-06
```

No pueden estar dentro de la semana del 06 de diciembre, tiene que estar en la semana anterior. Por lo que si la fecha resultante es mas grande que la fecha generada, se le ha de restar una semana. (en mi caso sumar por que estoy en recorriendo descendente el tiempo).

Espero haberme explicado bien.